# Is RSS feed a feasible & good option to inform users about the changes made on Parent level in Blueprint?

Tags: event-system, blueprint, 2013-sp1-hr1

I am sure everyone here might be handling this requirement in different ways & hence thought to get an optimised solution.
Today many of our country users are left outdated with the changes made at parent level if the items are localized.

We send the emails on each Live page publishing at the parent level including component details, but users end up receiving a lot of emails which is a pain.

I am now thinking to use RSS feed to post the details on weekly basis but would be interested to know if it is feasible and if you have any other good approach to deal this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Yash - did any of the below answers assist?

Comment: Hi Dylan, all the answers did help to get the leads but as we have a specific requirement and we are also thinking of upgrade to SDL Web 8.5, we didn't really implement anything yet.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using an RSS feed with the changes of the past week, why not use a virtual Folder with a search query in there that shows changed items in the past week.

We have added a similar folder to the DXA BluePrint lately (will be exposed in DXA 2.0), the principles are very simple. The Folder is named **Modified in the last 7 days** and its source contains:

```
<SearchFolder xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/SearchFolder">
    <GeneralParameters>
        <SearchQuery></SearchQuery>
        <SearchIn xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:1-1-2" Recursive="true" xlink:title="Building Blocks"></SearchIn>
    </GeneralParameters>
    <AdvancedParameters>
        <Modified>
            <LastDays>7</LastDays>
        </Modified>
    </AdvancedParameters>
</SearchFolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

No RSS feeds are available, based on my experience.

There are a couple of ways you can address your issue. You can write some event code to throw a warning in the CME, if content from the parent publication is published, while we have content in the child publications that are published.
You can also create a small GUI extension, that will perform the above, when you right-click on the page or component. Both will be manual invocations. You can do many things, if we have different use cases.

If a manual operation is not acceptable, you can write a TBB or resolver to also publish out the page (localized or not) from the child publications, if they are already published. This now becomes a different requirement though. If you are using a TBB, you may need additional event code for unpublish requirements.

If you are looking for a feed, you may be better off writing your published page information with the publication details from the parent and child publications to a custom database. You can then run a report or build your own RSS feed page and display it tridion using custom pages. This would need you to re-publish all your pages based on your database design.

You may have to choose what is acceptable (manual vs. automated) and whether this is functionality that an everyday publisher would use vs. an administrator. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in functionality for providing RSS feeds of changed components, but that's not to say that you couldn't create something. I would probably investigate the search API (rather than an Event System), which should allow you to retrieve a list of all components changed within a specified date range in a Publication (assuming that your search service etc. are working correctly). You could perhaps filter those search results to find only those items which are used.

I would question the suitability of an RSS feed, only because most of the end users I know don't know what one is and wouldn't really know how to access or use one. Perhaps you could summarise the changes in a weekly email instead? (If you really wanted an RSS feed for yourself or your more technical users then maybe you could generate the email from the feed?)